# Error 1001 with setup created by Visual Studio

Tags: c#

I have created an installer by Visual Studio 2017. The installer contains my Windows Services. When I tried to install the program, it gave me error:

> 1001: Specified service marked for deletion

I'm sorry that I can't have the log right now. I've found all over the Event Viewer but I found nothing.

Comment: Does your installer try to remove the service before installing it?

Comment: @stuartd I don't know but it's possible. Let me try restarting the computer

Answer (score 0):

It happens because you have another windows service with the same name that was installed and deleted but it is still working.

So you need stop the service and close all the windows of Service Console. If you can't stop the service kill it with task manager and open a new Service Console Windows to check if the service has been deleted. If the service still appear, as @k7s5a says, reboot you machine to complete the delete procces.

Comment: Well, I can't see the service in Task Manager

Comment: Your can find it with the exe's name, if it is not there then close all the Services Console windows to release all reference to that windows service. If not, use the las resource: reboot machine.

Answer (score -1):

You have to reboot the machine and try again.

Comment: Why I got a down vote? Restart definitely solve this problem.